# use solid fontawesome icons in `reactablefmtr::icon_assign()`

Tags: r, shiny, reactable, reactablefmtr

In the following example I have the regular version of the fontawesome `star` icon:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reactable)
library(reactablefmtr)

tibble(
  stars = 1:5
) %>% 
  reactable(
    columns = list(
      stars = colDef(
        show = TRUE, 
        name = "Stars",
        align = "center",
        cell = icon_assign(., icon = "star", fill_color = "gold", buckets = 5, show_values = "none")
      )
    )
  )
```

I am looking for a way to use the solid star version. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`icon_assign` relies on `shiny::icon` which would theoretically allow for using different `fa` classes:

```r
icon("star", class = "fas")
# vs
icon("star", class = "far")
```

produces the following two stars (BTW you said you want the solid form instead of the regular form, but if I try your code I already got the solid form [i.e. the filled star], so I assume you really want the regular form [i.e. the unfilled]),

[image: Solid and Regular Fontawesome Star]

However, looking into the code of `icon_assign` you see that `shiny::icon` is called without any further arguments.

Thus, you have basically 2 options:

1. Make a copy of `icon_assign` and allow for an additional `class` parameter to be passed to `shiny::icon`.
2. Create the icons yourself (i.e. skipping `icon_assign` altogether)

```
library(dplyr)
library(reactable)
library(reactablefmtr)
library(purrr)
library(htmltools)
tibble(
   stars = map_chr(1:5, ~ div(
      rep(list(
         list(icon("star", "far", style = "color: rgb(255, 215, 0)")),
         list(icon("star", "far", style = "color: rgb(211, 211, 211)"))
      ), c(.x, 5L - .x))) %>% 
         as.character()
   )) %>% 
   reactable(
      columns = list(
         stars = colDef(
            show = TRUE, 
            name = "Stars",
            align = "center",
            html = TRUE
         )
      )
   ) %>% 
   tagList(fontawesome::fa_html_dependency()) %>% 
   browsable()
```

[image: Table with regular stars created by defining the HTML with shiny icons]